# Elimination of repeated document in elasticsearch aggregation query

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

i have 5 documents of index which having a array of topics , 2 of them documents having a duplication of array something like below

```
       {
    "_index": "testindex",
    "_type": "testindex",
    "_id": "125",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "topics": [
            "Love",
            "Entertainment"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "testindex",
    "_type": "testindex",
    "_id": "126",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "topics": [
            "Health",
            "Fitness"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "testindex",
    "_type": "testindex",
    "_id": "127",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "topics": [
            "Health",
            "Fitness"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "testindex",
    "_type": "testindex",
    "_id": "128",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "topics": [
            "Sports",
            "Cricket"
        ],
    }
},
{
    "_index": "testindex",
    "_type": "testindex",
    "_id": "129",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "topics": [
            "Fit",
            "gym"
        ],
    }
}
```

here is my query of Elasticsearch

**GET testindex/_search**

```
  {
      "size":0,
      "aggs": {
        "topics": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "topics.keyword",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "testindex": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

***the result of my query is***

```
    "aggregations": {
    "topics": {}
      "buckets": [
        {
            "key": "health",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "testindex": {
                "hits": {
                    "total": 2,
                    "max_score": 6.3823323,
                    "hits": [
                        {
                            "_index": "testindex",
                            "_type": "testindex",
                            "_id": "126",
                            "_score": 1,
                            "_source": {
                                "topics": [
                                    "Health",
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "_index": "testindex",
                            "_type": "testindex",
                            "_id": "127",
                            "_score": 1,
                            "_source": {
                                "topics": [
                                    "Health"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "Fitness",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "testindex": {
                "hits": {
                    "total": 2,
                    "max_score": 6.3823323,
                    "hits": [
                        {
                            "_index": "testindex",
                            "_type": "testindex",
                            "_id": "126",
                            "_score": 1,
                            "_source": {
                                "topics": [
                                    "Fitness",
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "_index": "testindex",
                            "_type": "testindex",
                            "_id": "127",
                            "_score": 1,
                            "_source": {
                                "topics": [
                                    "Fitness"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
    ]
}
}
```

Actually i don't want the duplication of same document in top hits, i get the result of topics health and fitness separately with same document id , i just want one whether it is **fitness** or **health** ,
Thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt that the top hits results in your aggregation have a "topics" array with only a single element in it. The full "topics" array should come back. Did you edit the response?

Comment: Result is something like that, It just a test data

Comment: `top_hits` will always return documents, so if more than one documents are in that bucket, they will both be returned.

Comment: actually i don't want the duplication of same document in top hits, i get the result of topics **health** and **fitness** seperately with same document id , i just want one whether it is **fitness** or **health**

Comment: Well, the source cannot be modified in the search results, whether in top level this or inside aggregation top hits. Maybe with scripted fields, but I don't really see the point.

Comment: The duplication doesn't happen in a single bucket. It happens in cross buckets. According to the response I mentioned in my question, the **health** and **fitness** both are resulting doc ids `126, 127`. This is the cross bucket duplication which I want to prevent.

Comment: Those two buckets are completely independent, you're bucketing by topic, hence you get two topics (health and fitness) and within those two topics you're asking for document hits, which is what you're getting. The health bucket has no knowledge of what documents are being returned in the fitness bucket. Since both documents match each of the two buckets (they both have the same topics), they are returned in each bucket.

Comment: yes that what i am asking, i need single bucket whether it is **Fitness** or **health** is any solution ?

Comment: Set size to 1 instead of 10 in the top_hits aggregation :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168787/discussion-between-ali-ahmed-and-val).